# Updating several timers within QTableView

Tags: qt

I am working on a Qt widget (Qt 5.6) that will be a queue using a QTableView table to visualize a QStandardItemModel. My goal is to have the "Time Remaining" column display the amount of time remaining, active to the seconds.

My idea for solving this is to have each queue item have an accompanying "finish time", and display the delta between the finish time and the current time, which means that I will only have to update the current time every second, which will (ideally?) be able to indirectly update all the variables that are dependent on that current time.

Is this possible? I am not sure how to phrase it as a question better than just laying out the situation.

Thanks! (Using qt creator and c++, if it's any consideration)

Comment: Could you add some code of the standardItemModel  ?

Comment: I'd reimplement `QStandardItem::data()` to calculate the finish time, using the current time. When the timer procs, I'd save the current time (so the items can use it) and do a single call to `QStandardItemModel::dataChanged()` on the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

- Use a controller outside of the model and update the model every tick
- create your own `TableView` and refresh the delta time column every tick, based on the finish time in your model.
- create your own derived `StandardItemModel` that sends out a `dataChanged` signal for your delta column each tick

Either way, you might want to look into `QTimer` or some other mean of triggering an update for your `QTableView`.